# Streaming data in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

After streaming data in BigQuery, new data is available only for few moments in the table as I refresh the page data is gone but I can still query.The main problem is every time I am closing the tab and again access it from the storage I can see the data in table but again it goes when I refresh the page.

Answer (score 9):

The data is in the table. Sometimes you will see the message:

> This table has records in the streaming buffer that may not be visible in the preview.

The web UI is little buggy with displaying streamed or updated table details. If you run your query you will see the data you expect.

Comment: Is there any solution for that? I need to see the data in tables because my there is one more team and the need it.
Any solution for the bugs?
Thanks for the answer

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Just query the data! The preview isn't that valuable anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Adding extra information, after doing some research I found that if table is not altered for certain hours ( will update for exact hour),I was able to see the data in table.I think for streaming table verified to check whether it is getting updated or not.

Comment: Just to clarify this for anyone else - it's not necessarily 'buggy' but has to do with the way BigQuery handles streaming inserts. Essentially the data is in a buffer before being written. BigQuery is smart enough to be able to allow you to query and retrieve from the buffer (hence why querying works) but it won't appear until it's written. Good explanation here https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/life-of-a-bigquery-streaming-insert