# How to append to a table in BigQuery using Python BigQuery API

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I've been able to append/create a table from a Pandas dataframe using the [`pandas-gbq` package](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-gbq). In particular using the [`to_gbq` method](https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing.html). However, When I want to check the table using the BigQuery web UI I see the following message:

> This table has records in the streaming buffer that may not be visible in the preview.

I'm not the only one to ask, and it seems that [there's no solution to this yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38867744/streaming-data-in-bigquery).

So my questions are:
1. Is there a solution to the above problem (namely the data not being visible in the web UI).
2. If there is no solution to (1), is there another way that I can append data to an existing table using the Python BigQuery API? (Note the documentation says that I can achieve this by [running an asynchronous query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#appending-data) and using `writeDisposition=WRITE_APPEND` but the [link that it provides](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#asynchronous-queries) doesn't explain how to use it and I can't work it out).

Answer (score 0):

That message is just a UI notice, it should not hold you back.

To check data run a simple query and see if it's there.

To read only the data that is still in Streaming Buffer use this query:

```
#standardSQL    
SELECT count(1) 
FROM `dataset.table` WHERE _PARTITIONTIME is null
```

Comment: You're right. All of my data are there but it would be nice to not have this notice and to see the data as normal. Is there a way to do this without having to run an additional query on the table?

Comment: When the preview is not working for you you need to run queries. In case you are able to reconstruct a work and proof case why the preview doesn't work sometimes then you can submit an issue.

Answer (score 0):

While writing to table you use:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas


# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
dataframe, table_id, job_config=job_config
)  # Make an API request.
job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.
```

And that job config is a bigquery.LoadJobConfig class. You can instantiate it and pass it to the `load_table_from_dataframe` method.

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig( write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND")
```